# jQuery Validate not showing all error messages at once, only displaying one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've searched the web and read through the [jQuery Validate Docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) and I'm not finding out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a form in a modal that is using [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and everything works now. When I try to submit the form without the required fields, the text boxes turn red. However only one error message pops up, it looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the other `textbox`'s (ie: from the security question `textbox` to the password `textbox`) the error message for the text box pops up and I click into, but the other `textbox`'s error message goes away.

It should show "*Answer Required*" and "*Password Required*" in the error message `div`. I have tried using the *Validate* plugin's `errorPlacement`, `groups`, and other things without success.

My script looks like this:

```
  $('#QuestionAnswer').validate({
                        rules: {
                            question: {
                                required: true,
                                notEqual: '#answer'
                            },
                            answer: {
                                required: true
                            },
                            password: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            question: {
                                required: "Question Required",
                                notEqual: 'Question cannot be the same as Answer'
                            },
                            answer: {
                                required: "Answer Required"
                            },
                            password: {
                                required: "Please enter the user's password"
                        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                            $("#qaErrorLabel").html(error);
                            $("#qaErrorDiv").show();
                        }
                    });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div id="qaModaldiv" style="display:none;">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("QuestionAnswer", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    id = "QuestionAnswer",
    Name = "QuestionAnswer"
}))
{
            <div id="errorMsgCenter" style="font-size:12px;">
                @Html.ValidationSummary()

            </div>
            <div id="qaErrorDiv" class="error" style="font-size: 12px; display:none;">
                <label id="qaErrorLabel" class="validation-summary-errors"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" style="margin:25px;">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Security Question:</td>
                        <td> <input type="text" style="width:250px;" name="question" id="question" value="@Model.Question" maxlength="64" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Security Answer: </td>
                        <td> <input type="text" style="width:250px;" name="answer" id="answer" maxlength="64" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User's Password: </td>
                        <td> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
}
```

When I inspect element on the error that does pop up, none of the other errors are there, only the one is there. I have a sneaking suspicion I'm doing something wrong with the `errorPlacement` part, but I've played with that and can't get anything to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is errorPlacement called just once if you debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is exactly what I did to fix the error. I changed `.html` to `.append`. However by doing this the errors are not on a new line, they are right next to each other like this:

> My first error message.Mysecond error message.

Rather than this:

> My first error message.
>
> My second error message.

So to fix that I changed the code to look like this:

```
messages: {
    question: {
        required: "Question Required<br/>",
        notEqual: 'Question cannot be the same as Answer<br/>'
    },
    answer: {
        required: "Answer Required<br/>"
    },
    password: {
        required: "Please enter the user's password<br/>"
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $("#qaErrorLabel").append(error);
                $("#qaErrorDiv").show();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are overwriting the previous message with a new message. One element only has one `.innerHTML` property. `errorPlacement` is called once for each error. Each time the method is called, the `innerHTML` of the `qaErrorLabel` element is replaced with a new content. That's why you see only one message printed on the screen.

Comment: I had a feeling that it was something to do with that. Is there something else besides `errorPlacement` that I need to use? Or do I need to use `errorPlacement` differently?

Comment: @MaxPoshusta Well, instead of using the `html` method, you can create an `ul` element and append a `li` element to it for each error. When the field is okay, you can remove the corresponding `li` element.

Comment: Thank you. So something like this (from the Docs): `error.appendTo( element.parent("ul").next("ul") );`?